# PDE Problem on Eigenvalues and the Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation, laplacian, eigenfunctions

Let $a$ be any fixed real number. Consider the eigenvalue system:

$$
\begin{cases}
X'' + \lambda X = 0, & 0 ≤ x ≤ 1\\[0.1cm]
aX(0) = X(1)\\[0.1cm]
aX'(0) = -X'(1)
\end{cases}.
$$

Prove that if $a = \pm 1$, then every real $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Prove that if $a \not= 1$, then no real $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Approach:

So I looked for solutions of the ODE in the form:

$$X(x) = e^{bx}$$

Where I need to solve for b. Differentiation of $e^{bx}$ just multiplies the function by b, so then $X(x)$ becomes

$(b^2 + λ)*e^{bx} = 0$. And since $e^{bx}$ cannot be zero,

$$b^2 + λ = 0$$
So, $b=\pm\sqrt{-λ}x$
This gives the general form of
$X(x) = c_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x} + c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$

Where $X'(x) = c_1\sqrt{-\lambda}e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x} + c_2\sqrt{-\lambda}e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$ is the 2nd derivative. Plugging in the boundary conditions gives:

$X(0) = c_1+c_2$

$X'(0) = c_1-c_2$

$X(1) = c_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}} + c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}$

$X'(1) = c_1\sqrt{-\lambda}e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}} - c_1\sqrt{-\lambda}e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}$

I then tried solving for $a$

$a = \frac{X(1)}{X(0)} = \frac{c_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}} + c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}}{c_1+c_2}$

$a = \frac{X'(1)}{X'(0)} = \frac{c_1\sqrt{-\lambda}e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}} - c_2\sqrt{-\lambda}e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}}{c_1-c_2} $

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should first solve the differential equation (in dependence of $\lambda$).

Comment: @amsmath So I look for solutions of the form X(x) = e^(bx). Differentiation of e^(bx) just multiplies the function by b, so then X(x) becomes (b^2 + λ)*e^(bx) = 0. And since e^(bx) cannot be zero, I solve b^2 + λ = 0. Here is where I am stuck.

Comment: $b = \pm\sqrt{-\lambda}$. So, the general solution is $X(t) = ce^{\sqrt{-\lambda}t} + de^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}t}$. Be careful! You have to treat the case $\lambda = 0$ separately.

Comment: @amsmath that is the same as csinh(-λx) + dcosh(-λx), which is the form my professor prefers. However, I am not very familiar with the hyperbolic functions. 
When λ = 0 I know the general solution is X(t)=c + dt

Comment: If $\lambda < 0$, it doesn't have this cosine-sine form! Also, you forgot the square root. You don't have to deal with any hyperbolic functions. Just derive the general solution I gave you and plug in the boundary values.

Comment: I did as you said and got:
X(0) = c + d
X'(0) = c - d
X(1) = ce^(sqrt(-λ)) + de^(-sqrt(-λ))
X'(1) = c*(sqrt(-λ))*e^(sqrt(-λ)) - d*(-sqrt(-λ))*e^(-sqrt(-λ))

I then solved for a twice  and X'(1) / X'(0) 
$\frac{X(1)}{X(0)} = \frac{ce^(sqrt(-λ)) + de^(-sqrt(-λ))}{c+d}$
$\frac{X'(1)}{X'(0)} = \frac{c(sqrt(-λ))e^(sqrt(-λ)) - d(sqrt(-λ))e^(-sqrt(-λ))}{c-d}$

Comment: @amsmath I updated my question with my most recent work more clearly, if that helps.

Comment: You took the wrong general solution. Look again at my second comment.

Comment: @amsmath I added some missing negative signs, my apologies. Do i need to yes out each case $\lambda > 0, \lambda = 0, \lambda < 0$ ? I thought each case had a different general solution? 

$c + dx$ for $\lambda = 0$

$X(x) = ce^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x} + de^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$ OR $c\sinh{(\sqrt{-\lambda}x} + d\cosh{(\sqrt{-\lambda}x}e$ for $\lambda < 0$

$X(x) = ce^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x} + de^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$  OR  $c\sin{-\lambda x}+d\cos(-\lambda x}$ for $\lambda > 0$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $b^2+\lambda=0$ has solutions $b=\pm\sqrt{-\lambda}$. So the general solution is
$$ X(x)=C_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}. $$
Using the initial conditions $aX(0) = X(1),aX'(0) = -X'(1)$, one has
$$ 
a(C_1+C_2)=C_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}},\tag{1}$$
and
$$a\sqrt{-\lambda}(C_1-C_2)=-\sqrt{-\lambda}(C_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}-C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}).\tag{2}$$
The second equation above can be simplified as
$$ a(C_1-C_2)=-C_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}. \tag{3}$$
Now (1)+(3) and (1)-(3) give
$$ aC_1=C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}, aC_2=C_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$$
from which it is easy to see
$$ (a^2-1)C_1C_2=0.$$
Case 1: $a^2-1=0$ or $a=\pm1$. Then $X(x)=C_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$ is an eigenfunction (at least one of $C_1,C_2$ is not zero) with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Case 2: $a^2-1\neq 0$ or $a\not=\pm1$. Then from (4), one has $C_1C_2=0$. So one of $C_1,C_2$ is zero. Suppose $C_1=0$. Then (1) and (2) become
$$ 
aC_2=C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}},-aC_2=C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}} $$
from which one has $C_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}=0$ or $C_2=0$. Thus $X(x)=0$. Similarly $C_2=0$ implies $C_1=0$. Thus $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.